# What's the rule for knowns and unknowns when dealing with derivatives

Tags: calculus, derivatives

So a rule of thumb when doing basic algebra is you must have as many equations as you have unknowns. For example:

$0=4x+6y^2$

$3x=2\sqrt{y}$

You have two equations and two unknowns and thus can solve for both x and y

However I don't know how this rule (if it even applies) works if you have a differential equation instead for example

$0=4x+6y^2$

$\frac{dy}{dx}=2x$

Does the second equation still count as one equation or does it introduce additional information that's needed to solve the problem? Does the general (rule 1 equation for 1 unknown) still work for all cases? What about higher order differential equations?

Comment: Note that this rule doesn't even hold for linear equations, although at least for linear equations it is easy to characterize when you have zero, one, or infinitely many solutions. As you generalize the kinds of equations to systems of polynomial equations, or fully general systems of $n$ constraints in $n$ dimensions, the "rule" becomes a rule of thumb, at best.

Comment: @user7530 One might even say that the rule is *necessary* but not *sufficient*.

Comment: @Arkamis I'm not sure it's even necessary -- for instance the single equation $x^2+y^2 = 0$ in two real variables has a unique solution.

Comment: @user7530 The restriction to reals, in a sense, becomes an additional condition. I suppose I'm using "equations" to more broadly mean "restrictions." That's perhaps a jump (but a useful one!)

Comment: @Arkamis So how about $x\bar{x}+y\bar{y}=0$? ;)

Comment: Is there any quick rule of thumb or check you can make for these types of systems of equations to ensure you have enough information to solve the problem? My engineering exams have a lot of tedious math so you can waste a lot of time partially solving a problem only to find you lack enough information.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, you can still use substitution:

$$2x = \frac{dy}{dx} \implies 0=2\frac{dy}{dx}+6y^2.$$

Now solve.

More generally, this is a more complicated type of system known as a *differential-algebraic equation* (DAE).

We may view it in vector form as

$$\mathbf{F}\left(\frac{dy(x)}{dx}, y(x), x\right) \stackrel{\textrm{def}}{=} \begin{pmatrix} 4x+6y^2 \\ \frac{dy(x)}{dx}-2x \end{pmatrix} = \mathbf{0}.$$

What you have conceptualized is known as a *semi-explicit DAE of index 1*. These types of DAEs include a purely algebraic term, and a differential equation term.

Solvability is more restrictive than for systems of algebraic equations. For index 1 DAEs, we must have that the purely algebraic term is solvable in terms of $y$. At this point, I'm just repeating things that are already present on the [Wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_algebraic_equation#Semi-explicit_DAE_of_index_1), but the system you have found belongs to a family of problems that can actually be quite challenging to solve.

Answer (score 0):

Once integrated, the differential equation becomes an ordinary equation but that includes an integration constant, i.e. a new unknown.

In your example,

$0=4x+6y^2$

$\frac{dy}{dx}=2x\implies y=x^2+C$

Comment: Yeah I realized I forgot the constant once I finished the post. Is there a different rule of thumb I could use? I ask because I'm an engineering student so we usually use at least a couple differential equations on our exams and I want to make sure I have enough information to solve the problem (otherwise I get halfway through the solution before I realize I'm missing something)